# would shared_ptr be aware of intermittence reference?

Tags: c++

by intermittence reference I mean the following

```
shared_ptr<int> a = new int(100);
int* i = a;
shared_ptr<int> b = i;
```

would the reference count of b be two?

also if it is aware, would still be valid in the following code?

```
//
shared_ptr<int> a = new int(100);

{// workspace

 int* i = a;
 shared_ptr<int> b = i;

}// end of workspace
```

If no to above question, how could I achieve it?
I would to make my memory allocation safe by using smart pointer. I have a data structure tree that would create new tree nodes (pointers to allocated memory) that is either inserted into tree or passed out.
If it is within the tree, no problem, I can control the life cycle. If it is passed out, then I have no control.

Comment: It won't compile.

Comment: @user17732522 this certainly answers my question. How would you recommend to achieve it?

Comment: I mean, your syntax is just wrong in every line. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/cGWMo4P78) is a modification that at least compiles.

Comment: achieve what exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you wrote in your example will not compile. But to answer the spirit of what I think your question is here is an example

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> a = std::make_shared<int>(100);
    int* i = a.get();
    std::shared_ptr<int> b(i);
}
```

This does not have `a` and `b` related as far as reference counting. Instead they both (mistakenly) take ownership of the same underlying pointer, pointed at by `i` and [will result](https://godbolt.org/z/fEhxfocKo) in a `double free or corruption` when `a` falls out of scope since they both try to delete it.

The correct way for both `shared_ptr` to reference the same underlying pointer and have correct reference counting behavior is simply

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> a = std::make_shared<int>(100);
    std::shared_ptr<int> b = a;
}
```